# What is selectivity threshold?

Tags: apex, query, performance

In the example mentioned here([Force.com Query Optimizer](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/07/maximizing-the-performance-of-force-com-soql-reports-and-list-views.html))

What happens for the below scenario:

1. Total number of Records in Account table : 2,500,000
2. And all the records are created on Jan 1st 2015.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate  > 2013-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Selectivity threshold for the above table is : 525,000

1) So what happens in the above scenario? The total number of rows the above query trying to retrieve are way more than the selectivity threshold.

2) Blog says that query optimizer drives the index if it is less than threshold in this case it is not, so what happens?

Comment: This session from DF last year had a good discussion of this. Try starting at this time index: https://youtu.be/uyyXdEIieN4?t=11m55s